# sets and enclosing braces

Tags: formatting, brackets

How can I denote a set of numbers with curly braces around them (curly braces are usually the standard for sets in mathematical textbooks). I tried the following:

```
$d={3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1}$
```

Tex rendered the text without the curly braces

Comment: you'll need `\{...\}` to make `TeX` understand that you want to display them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`$d=\{3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1\}$` should do the trick

Comment: ahhhh. I tried the escaping in the wrong places...

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus depending on your preference, `$d=\{\,3,2,2,1,1,1\,\}$` can also be used to adjust the spacing a bit.